# Database hit reduction .net?

Tags: .net

In a single webmethod in .net webservice there are 4 times DB hit (for different tables), apart from using stored procedures, is there any means which i can follow to reduce the db hit?

Answer (score 3):

Write a single query that collects all the data you require.

There is almost always a way to do one query.

```
Select A.A1, A.A2, A.A3, B.B1, B.B2, B.B3
From TableB B
    Inner Join (
        Select A1, A2, A3
        From TableA
        Where A1 = @Id
    ) A On B.B1 = A.A2
```

Comment: The second select statement has a parameter which has to come from I query, any other approach?

Comment: Thanks ChaosPandion, for ex:

Select A1.Column1 from table1 where userid='Karthick';
Select A2.Column1 from table2 where A2.Column=output of first query;
Select A2.Column1 from table2 where A2.Column=A1.Column1

How do we can approach to make this to a single db hit?

Answer (score 2):

Look into [ASP.Net Data Caching](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043655/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100902-1.aspx).

You can keep your result set for the duration of your request, and even longer, reducing your database round trips.

Answer (score 1):

Use [caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c.aspx) to store values from the database in server memory. There are many options here, depending on what you need.